# Firebase TIMESTAMP query android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want make query in firebase TIMESTAMP

```
    mDatabase.child("TripSummry").orderByChild("TIMESTAMP").startAt(Selecteddate()).
```

if today Selecteddate is 22/2/2017
I get result of

```
22/2/2017
23/2/2017
24/2/2017
```

till last one
......................................................

all values is in long

and Selecteddate is function return long

I wanne to get only 22/2/2017

Comment: duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42249524/sorting-items-position-using-firebaserecycleradapter

Comment: No Not my Question
but Thank , This Link helps me Too :)

Comment: Add a child `Timestamp` to each post and assign a long value. For example current timestamp is '1489654177035'. This will, later on, enable you to manipulate date according to a specific date in your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `endAt()` with query too.

```
.startAt(Selecteddate()).endAt(tomorrowSelectedDate).
```

Calculate `tomorrowSelectedDate` as `Selecteddate()` + 1 day

Answer (score 2):

Try mDatabase.child("TripSummry").orderByChild("attime")**.equalTo**(Selecteddate()).

Replace ".startAt" with ".equalTo"

Good luck :)

[Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#equalTo(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: equal to not working cause
TODAY VALUE IS 1489710464594
AND SELECTED DAY IS 1489701656589

Comment: Don't yell please. In the example in your question you've only given dates in the format `dd/MM/yyyy`. Now you show timestamps in your comment. Please edit your question to include the minimum, *complete* information that reproduces the problem. This includes a representative snippet of your actual JSON as text (which you can get by clicking Export JSON in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/)) and the code that you use to query the data (with real values, no variables that we don't know the value of).

Comment: Iam Just new here and this is my first question ,
so My Mistake 
sorry sir , :)